# How to assign a set of text values to a string array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

How can I assign a set of text values to an array? Nothing I tried is working!

```
Months = Array("Jan", "Feb", ..., "Dec")
```

and others I tried do not work!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's something about VB:  http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18322

> Visual Basic doesn't provide any way
>   to declare an array and initialize its
>   elements at the same time. In most
>   cases you end up with setting
>   individual elements one by one, as in:

```
  Dim strArray(0 To 3) As String
  strArray(0) = "Spring" 
  strArray(1) = "Summer"
  strArray(2) = "Fall"
  strArray(3) = "Winter"
```

> Under VB4, VB5, and VB6 you can create
>   an array of Variants on the fly, using
>   the Array() function:

```
  Dim varArray() As Variant 
  varArray() = Array("Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter")
```

> but there is no similar function to
>   create arrays of data types other than
>   Variant. If you're using VB6, however,
>   you can create String arrays using the
>   Split() function:

```
  Dim varArray() As String 
  ' arrays returned by Split are always zero-based 
  varArray() = Split("Spring;Summer;Fall;Winter", ";")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can only do it like this:

```
 dim months(2) as string

 months(0) = "Jan"
 months(1) = "Feb"
 months(2) = "Mar"
```

Comment: It's pretty annoying.  I try to use Collections whenever possible

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about vbscript then this works:

```
months = Array("may","june","july")
```

If it's vb.net then:

```
dim months() as string = {"may","june","july"}
```